# How to access XML document in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

I don't know why this code is not working, I was using Apache Tomcat 7 but yet its not working as I thought.

Problem in JavaScript or html tell me so I never repeat that mistake

```
<script>
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.open("GET", "catalog.xml", false);
    xmlhttp.send();

    xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;


    document.write("<table border='5'>");

    var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("cd");

    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {

        document.write("<tr>");
        document.write("<td>");

        document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("title" [0].childNodes[0].nodeValue));

        document.write("</td>");
        document.write("</tr>");

        document.write("<tr>");
        document.write("<td>");

        document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("artist" [0].childNodes[0].nodeValue));

        document.write("</td>");
        document.write("</tr>");
    }

    document.write("</table>");
</script>
```

[image: XML Code LINK]

Comment: What's happening vs what's supposed to happen? Did you check the developer console (Ctrl+Shift+I in Chrome/FF, F12 in Edge)? Does it show any error messages? Does the network tab show the HTTP request being sent? What have you tried to determine the point of the error so far? Please do some basic debugging.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<catalog>
  <cd>
   <title> C++  </title>
   <artist> Ram  </artist>
  </cd>


  <cd>
   <title> JAVA   </title>
   <artist> Shyam  </artist>
  </cd>

</catalog> i have access this XML in my code in shows nothing , i am using table for retrieving values but its not working.

Comment: any **errors** in the developer tools console? Note: synchronous XHR **and** `document.write` - have you not seen a browser since the 90's?

Comment: yes sir , i saw the errors how can i solve it ..? TypeError: "title"[0].childNodes is undefined. new error :-The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared

Comment: XML is text, so please put the XML text in the question, rather than an image of it. Since you are getting an error, please put that in the question as well. Presently the question does not contain everything the reader needs to know, and putting it in the comments does not count (you can delete those).